# ExternalContext#dispatch() doesn't work

Tags: jsf

I have server-side coundown counter. When it == 0, method should execute `ExternalContext#dispatch()`, but it didn't do it. Method `ExternalContext#redirect()` works correctly on this place.

```
....
        }else{
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("result.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
....
```

I tried a few ways of the spelling url(`result,result.xhtml,\result.xhtml` etc.) with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way to let JSF navigate to a different view.

If you're inside an action method, you should be returning it as string instead.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "result.xhtml";
}
```

Or if you're not inside an action method and couldn't change it to a fullworthy action method for some unclear reason, then use [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html#handleNavigation%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, "result.xhtml");
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but it works like `ExternalContext#redirect()` in my case. I need "forced" navigation, which would simulate pressing `<h:commandButton>` or working action method.

Comment: No, it doesn't perform a redirect at all. It performs a forward. It works only like `ExternalContext#redirect()` if you use `result.xhtml?faces-redirect=true` as outcome.