# How can I navigate to another page in managed bean?

Tags: jsf, redirect, navigation, forward

I am trying to forward a page in my managed bean with the commandbutton:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" value="Go to another page" />
```

The following line:

```
public void action() throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("another.xhtml");
}
```

redirects the page, not forwards. I have seen a similar question to this and tried the given solution:

```
public void action() throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("another.xhtml");
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Index: 0, Size: 0
```

So how can I forward to a page from a managed bean?

Comment: can you post exception stack trace?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just return it as action method return value.

```
public String action() {
    return "another.xhtml";
}
```

If you're in turn not doing anything else than navigating, then you could also just put the string outcome directly in `action` attribute.

```
<h:commandButton action="another.xhtml" value="Go to another page" />
```

However, this is in turn a rather poor practice. You should not be performing POST requests for plain page-to-page navigation. Just use a simple button or link:

```
<h:button outcome="another.xhtml" value="Go to another page" />
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton/)
- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one)
- [ExternalContext#dispatch() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108896/externalcontextdispatch-doesnt-work/)
- [JSF implicit vs. explicit navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037884/jsf-implicit-vs-explicit-navigation/)

Comment: thanks a lot, i think i did not know the difference between button and  commandbutton. Just one more question, let us say for two pages i use the same managed bean, and at the page1 i have a textbox, i fill it and press button (not command button) setter and getter works and some variable is bound to value of that box. Then page1 is navigated to text2. You said that simple button does not perform a post request, so in page2 can i have the value of that variable which was bound to the value of the textbox in page1? Or do i have to pass it as a parameter to page2?

Comment: Depends on the concrete functional requirement. Why do you need to show results of POST request in a different view? Can't you just show the results conditionally in the same view by e.g. `rendered="#{not empty bean.results}"`? See also the 2nd "See also" link for recommendations.