# Bean doesn't dispatch to another page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I've a problem with a bean that doesn't dispatch the response to another page.
This is the code:

```
        @ManagedBean(name = "ssoServiceBean")
    public class SSOServiceBean {

        @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.samlRequest}")
        private String samlRequest;

        @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.relayState}")
        private String relayState;


        @PostConstruct
        public void submit() {

            System.out.println("1) PostConstruct method called");

            //samlRequest = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("samlRequest");

            //relayState = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("relayState");        

            processResponse();
        } 

 //getters and setters omitted for succinctness

        private void processResponse(){

            System.out.println("2) Processing response");

            String uri;

            if(samlRequest != null && !samlRequest.equals("") && relayState != null && !relayState.equals("")) {

                System.out.println("SAMLRequest: "+samlRequest);
                System.out.println("RelayState: "+relayState);

                uri = "challenge.xhtml";

                System.out.println("3) Sending challenge...");  

            } else {

                uri = "dashboard.xhtml";

                System.out.println("3) Sending dashboard...");
            }

            try {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch(uri);
                System.out.println("4) Done.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the `dispatch()` method doesn't work properly, and seems to be ignored.

Infact the system responses with an error of the related bean's page `ssoservice.xhtml`

I've used the `Postconstruct` annotation because with this bean I've to intercept POST parameters that come from a third-party page.
Once I've received the post parameters, I've to render the  `challenge.xhtml`  page, WITHOUT using a redirect directive.

Nextly, the user will submit  `challenge.xhtml`  to the related bean `ChallengeBean.java` .

So, what is the problem? Why dispatch doesn't work?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163457/externalcontext-dispatch-not-working check if its a `ajax` request

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I'm not using ajax functionalities

Comment: Then check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108896/externalcontextdispatch-doesnt-work

Comment: @Subodh Joshi, your solution doesn't work. My bean reponses its page, and doesn't render challenge.xhtml

Comment: @BalusC, your solution doesn't work. My bean reponses its page, and doesn't render challenge.xhtml

Comment: @BalusC No one... Could be a problem I'm using PostConstruct annotation?

Comment: @BalusC PostConstruct works properly in order to intercept post parameters from a form that comes from an external site (form's action is my bean's url).
But from the bean, I cannot render challenge.xhtml view
The submitter form is a simple html form, with no jsf backend

Comment: @BalusC thanks Balus! Using <f:event type="preRenderVieW"> now it works, but the rendered view doesn't have any JS ora primeface's components rendered. Why?!